# How to handle statuscode 307 redirect with jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm having a lot of trouble with the `307 Temporary Redirect` statusCode using jquery.

I have an apache server that returns a 307 when needed. The 307 is getting thrown properly (I can see this with firebug or a wireshark trace), but I can't seem to get the redirect to trigger.

```
$.ajax({
    url: someURL,
    type: 'GET',
    processData: false,
    data: someData,
    cache: true,
    timeout: 5000,
    statusCode: {
        307: function() {
            alert('307'); // this does NOT get called
        }
    },
    error: function(request, status, error){
        try {
            console.log(request.getAllResponseHeaders());
        }
        catch (err) { }
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, response){
        try {
            console.log(response.getAllResponseHeaders());
        }
        catch (err) { }
    });
```

I wanted to check out the headers so I could redirect using the `getAllResponseHeaders()` method. This works fine for 200's but the 307 never triggers (in the `success` nor `error` handler)

One thing I noticed when using Firebug to examine the traffic is that right after the redirect an ajax `GET` is sent to the server with the url of the redirect! This results in a failure however.

So, what gives?

**Edit:**
I tried this with jquery 1.5.1 and 1.6.1

Comment: Make sure the body of your HTTP response contains at least a blank space.  It will help make browsers act better.  There is a Firefox add-on call 'Live HTTP Headers' which might help debug this. You are using jQuery v 1.5 or higher, correct?

Comment: @ Teddy. I tried this with jquery 1.5.1 and 1.6.1. Also, the entire redirect html page is being returned with the 307

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I did some more research and it appears that a 307 is automatically handled by the browser, and is not able to be intercepted by jquery.

I ended up using a different statusCode to do the redirect (`410 Gone`).

This probably isn't the best solution, but I don't have access to the apache server code.